# Can the length of shortened git branch names be changed in eclipse (egit)?

Tags: eclipse, egit

We prefix all our branches with the JIRA ticket keys, like `ABC-1111`. As we have now reached 10,000 tickets, we got to `ABC-12345`, but with `origin/` in the beginning, Eclipse is only showing us `origin/ABC-1234...`, which is not very helpful.

Can the size of the box showing the branch names be configured somehow? Even removing the `...` would probably give enough space for one more digit, which is all we need.

Comment: Where exactly do you see the shortened branch names? I cannot reproduce this in the current Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

That in the *History* view the shortening leads to a longer label cannot be seen in recent Eclipse versions, or to be more precise, in recent EGit versions. Maybe you just missed to keep your Eclipse including EGit up to date.

The shortening of branch names in the *History* view can be configured in the **preferences: *Version Control (Team) > Git > History: Maximum characters to show for a branch*** (and via the checkbox *Shorten long tag and branch names at the front*):

[image]

Comment: Yes, I really missed that. Thanks!